# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method error

Tags: android, listview, binding, sqliteopenhelper

I am getting the following error from my code

> 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   getReadableDatabase() from the type SQLiteOpenHelper'

in the `Database.java` file. If I use Eclipse to solve the error then an error happens in the `FavouriteScreen.java` file. Anyone know how to solve it?

***FavouritesScreen.java***

```
// Get a Cursor for the list items
Cursor listCursor = Database.GetFavouritesList();
startManagingCursor(listCursor);

// set the custom list adapter
setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));
```

and

***Database.java***

```
public static Cursor GetFavouritesList(){
try
{
return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT SocietyName FROM Favourites",null));
}
catch(SQLiteException e)
{
Log.e("Favourites", e.toString());
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: static `Cursor`, uhm, for what jesus god? I suggest you rather use static method for getting instance of dbhelper(singleton design pattern) than `Cursor`. This sounds like not correct designated app logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getReadableDatabase()` is a **instance** method, not a **class** method. You need an instance, e.g:

```
public static Cursor GetFavouritesList(SQLiteOpenHelper helper){
try
{
return(helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT SocietyName FROM Favourites",null));
}
catch(SQLiteException e)
{
Log.e("Favourites", e.toString());
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you are doing something not allowed! Solutions:

1. Put all the code for `getReadableDatabase()` in the function being sure not to call non-static functions.
2. Make `getReadableDatabase()` static.
3. Make `getReadableDatabase()` non-static and change how you call it:

   ```
   Database database = new Database();
   Cursor listCursor = database.GetFavouritesList();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are trying to use a non-static method within your static method. The `getReadableDatabase()` should also be static, for this should work.